# Are partition sizes displayed in megabytes or mebibytes during installation?

Tags: installation, partitioning

Good day, Ladies and Gentlemen!

Just to reassure myself: As far as I read in here, Ubuntu uses the correct decimal base interpretation of the MB prefix. So, in Nautilus, a file of 1MB is actually really 10<sup>3</sup> KB (1000 kilobytes) and 1GB = 10<sup>3</sup> MB (1000 megabytes).

However, I want to know if the same is true during the installation of Ubuntu, when creating the partitions manually. Am I right to enter 20000MB if I want a 20GB partition?

Comment: Uhm Nautilus uses the "i" prefix.. MiB, gparted uses MiB too.

Comment: No, Nautilus uses MB, i.e. decimal base. MiB is binary base. And GParted is not used during installation. I want to know if Ubuntu's partitioning tool during installation uses MB or MiB.

Comment: Mine is set to MiB but in the LiveCD is in MB, strange I didn't change that, gparted is a front end  for GNU Parted which is the same tool used by the Ubuntu Installer so it's basically the same. When I pick "Do Something else" the space is displayed as GB not in MB.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I tested it today. Simply by doing a fresh install. Ubuntu uses MB during installation, i.e. the decimal base. However, GParted shows the partition size in MiB.

And in Kubuntu, it's total crap. Because both, Dolphin AND the partition manager, show file/partition sizes in MiB.

This is totally inconsistent. It should be the same systemwide, during install and after.